# "Preload additional info" error

Tags: editor, pydev

For some reason, every time I start aptana studio I get pop-up warnings about:

An internal error occurred during: "Preload additional info".

Any idea what that is?

TIA!

Comment: I got it after install pydev (downloaded the zip file and copy the unziped folders) as well...

Answer (score 10):

Your Project file is corrupt. I had the same problem after moving my workspace to a dropbox folder and accessing it with two computers.

Solution:

1. Within Eclipse: Remove old project from Eclipse (do NOT delete the files!)
2. Within Finder / Explorer: Rename the old project folder to some backup-name
3. Within Eclipse: Create a new project under the old name
4. Within Finder / Explorer: Copy all .py-files (NOT .PYC!) and auxilary files for your project into the the new project folder (3)
5. Within Eclipse: Refresh (F5) your project
6. enjoy ;-)

Comment: not working for me... got the same error after install pydev

Answer (score 4):

Fedora 17 // 3.6.6-1.fc16.i686 // Eclipse SDK - Juno // Version: 4.2.1

In addition to the other fine posts, I too use a dropbox between two machines and have had my project file go caput.

1.) Backup your workspace folder to workspacebu. Recreate the dir workspace (empty folder). Open eclipse and then select import under the file menu.

2.) Choose Existing Projects into Worspace under the General Tab, browse to your backup workspacebu dir and click ok. From the now populated "Projects:" window, select the projects to import.

3.) Finally, select Copy projects into workspace and click finish.

Should be good to go!

Final note - take note of how you setup your layout.. If you take this route, you will have to recreate your eclipse perspective(s) layout.

Comment: I used to use Dropbox to sync files because it worked great between windows and the linux world, but a friend recently sent me this article about Dropbox and its security. I'd give it a quick read if you are concerned with security. [DropBox Reverse engineered](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/woot13/woot13-kholia.pdf)

Comment: btw... i will still use dropbox for some stuff... just wanted to share a good article.

Answer (score 2):

Got this error on PyDEV when trying to open python file in Python editor with no interpreter configured.

Add an interpreter in PyDEV:

```
Preferences -> PyDEV -> Python Interpreter
```

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this problem repeatedly.  (The answer from zaphorg corrected my problem each time for a day or two.) I don't have dropbox, but I tracked my problem to Jungledisk.  I suspect that any file sync service can be responsible for this type of project file corruption.

In my case, Jungledisk was set to merge my folders with the network drive in the cloud.  Somehow it was corrupting the project file.

SOLUTION: I changed the Sync Folder Configuration on Jungledisk to "Make the network drive match this folder".  (It used to be "Merge this folder with the network drive.")  I reapplied the zaphorg solution one last time, and the problem has never reappeared.

Note that I am only syncing this one computer to a network drive as backup.  There is no second computer that should be changing the file on the network drive and pushing those changes to me (thereby corrupting the project file), but the fact remains that my project file kept getting corrupted until I made the change above.

---

Detailed instructions for what I did for 32-bit Windows 7 and JungleDisk Version 3.16 Win32

1. Right-click on the JungleDisk icon in the Windows system tray.  (You may need to left-click on the little up arrow: Show hidden icons)
2. Left-click on Configure
3. In the left column, expand your Online Disk by left-clicking the '+' sign.  (If you have multiple online disks, you need to figure out which one(s) are syncing to the folder containing your project files.  You find this out by looking in item 6 below.)
4. In the left column, expand your Network Drive by left-clicking on the '+' sign to the left
5. In the left column, left-click your Sync Folder setting.
6. In the main section, select the Sync Folder that has your project folder in it.
7. Left-click the "Folder Options" button to bring up the Sync Folder Configuration window.
8. Change the dropdown selection in the How to Sync section to "Make the network drive match this folder"

I strongly suspect that I could also have eliminated my problem by using the "Edit Wildcards..." option to simply not sync the project file, but I haven't verified this.

Comment: I have the same problem, too, due to syncing two computers via Insync. But I never paid attention to it and nothing went wrong ever since. Is it really necessary to correct this problem? Thanks.

Comment: I agree that it never caused me any observable problems (except for the annoying error messages), but I decided to stop the syncing since it seemed to be bothering the project file and I wasn't sure if it might cause a real problem sometime.  For me, I was really only intending a one-directional sync, so there wasn't really a benefit to the syncing in the other direction.  I'm not sure if there is any real danger if you are truly doing bidirectional syncing.

Answer (score 0):

If your project file was being deduplicated by your OS, JD is screwing up the sync.  The reparsepoint (symlink) data is no longer valid and needs to be removed every time JD "syncs" the folder.  They have NO IDEA how to deal with deduplicated files, and their CTO refuses to accept that it's their problem.